# How to install lib1394 i386 (32bit) version on ubuntu 11.10 amd64

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries

I have an old acquisition program for a firewire that seems to need the 32bits version of the library `libraw1394.so` .

Some notes, about the problem:

I think that the output of `uname -m` indicates that I have an ubuntu 64bits installed:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

If I execute ldd on my application, the output indicates that lib1394.so was not found:

```
$ ldd ./smallv
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76e9000)
    libsvs.so => /usr/local/svs/bin/libsvs.so (0xf76c7000)
    libsvscalc.so => /usr/local/svs/bin/libsvscalc.so (0xf76b7000)
    libsvscap.so => /usr/local/svs/bin/libsvscap.so (0xf76a0000)
    libfltk.so.1.1 => /usr/local/svs/bin/libfltk.so.1.1 (0xf761a000)
    libfltk_gl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/svs/bin/libfltk_gl.so.1.1 (0xf7612000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libGLU.so.1 (0xf7573000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 (0xf74a1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf73b5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf739a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7370000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf71f1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf71d3000)
    libdcap.so => /usr/local/svs/bin/libdcap.so (0xf71c5000)
    libraw1394.so.8 => not found
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXext.so.6 (0xf71b2000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6 (0xf707c000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.280.13 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.280.13 (0xf7079000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.280.13 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libnvidia-glcore.so.280.13 (0xf5767000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf575e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf5759000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76ea000)
    libraw1394.so.8 => not found
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libxcb.so.1 (0xf573a000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXau.so.6 (0xf5735000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf572e000)
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
$ ./smallv
./smallv: error while loading shared libraries: libraw1394.so.8: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

The library is locted in `/usr/lib/` but it is and ELF63 version:

```
$ readelf -h /usr/lib/libraw1394.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4460
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          58768 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         26
  Section header string table index: 25
```

I have been searching a solution in various posts. So, I think that I have the source code of the applications so that I should be able to compile it. So I have to solutions, but I do not know how to execute them:

solution 1) Install the i386 (32bits) version of the library 
solution 2) Compile the application again

I have been reading posts and it seems that I should use either GetLibs either ia32-libs either multiarch. Please, any feedback to the problem will be helpful!
Thanks a lot!

jespestana

Comment: I don't understand very well. But if what you want to do is install that package, then you need to enter this command: `sudo apt-get install libraw1394-11:i386` in terminal. That solve your problem?

Comment: @Lucio I get the impression the author is probably already aware of the install method you recommend.

Comment: @Lucio, Ah ok! I will try that on monday! I have been some time looking in forums for the solution. So I posted the things that seemed more interesting to me here. I did not know about the ":i386" to "sudo apt-get install".

Comment: I did not know about that option, @Magpie, I do not know so much about linux. I have been using it one year and a half, and there are many things I still do not know about. I feel praised hehe! But it is just that I have tried many things already regarding this issue...

Comment: I stand corrected! It's always hard to get a balance between assuming too much knowledge and patronising people. @jespestana sudo apt-get install is an important command you must familiarise yourself with if you are to use ubuntu!

Comment: Now the application works, I just needed to install de i386 version of the library with the command `sudo apt-get install libraw1394-11:i386`.
Magpie, I add to my to-do list learning more about `sudo apt-get install` (I use it, but I do not know what options it offers).
Lucio, if you post your comment as answer I will be able to tag the answer as solved.
Thanks a lot to both!

Comment: My advice: install synaptics package manager. This will tell you all the packages that you can install. Also look into learning how to add repositories via terminal using the sudo add-apt-repository command

Comment: Please, any of you, Magpie or @Lucio if you answer the question (with the same stuff you have put into the comments) I will tag the question as solved! I mean, the application already worked with the ``sudo apt-get install :i386` option. Thanks again!

Comment: @jespestana I'm glad that this have functioned for you. I've translated my comment into a new answer. If you want, you can upvote my answer and [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483). Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're right, your system is using the 64 bits architecture.

As you said that a solution for your problem could be *install i386 (32bits) version of the library*, I have told you how to do it:

1. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Enter this command: `sudo apt-get install libraw1394-11:i386`

Now you should have installed the 32-bits version of the `libraw` library.